# Unable to connect to MySQL database using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming and I have been trying to run a PHP application from Murachs PHP and MySQL instructional book, the source code is actually from their website, but have been getting an error message. The error message is as follows;

"Database Error There was an error connecting to the database.  The database must be installed as described in the appendix.  MySQL must be running as described in chapter 1.  Error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mgs_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I downloaded XAMPP and it is running fine but for some reason I am unable to use the MySQL database. I have searched and Googled and searched some more for the last two days but I can't seem to find a solution.

I remember setting up a username and password during installation and I set up a username called "root" and a password through PHPMyAdmin yesterday but why will this application not run?

Any help is appreciated.

Update #1

Here are samples of the code that creates the database, the user and the password.

This is downloaded from Murach's site so the code should be good. I am thinking there is something wrong with the XAMPP/MySQL that will not allow a connection to the database.

```
/*****************************************
* Create the my_guitar_shop1 database
*****************************************/
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_guitar_shop1;
CREATE DATABASE my_guitar_shop1;
USE my_guitar_shop1;  -- MySQL command

-- Create a user named mgs_user
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON *
TO mgs_user@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'pa55word';
```

Update #2

I created the user "mgs_user@localhost" in PHPMyAdmin and gave it permissions and now I get the following error;

"Database Error
There was an error connecting to the database.

The database must be installed as described in the appendix.

MySQL must be running as described in chapter 1.

Error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_guitar_shop1'  "

The code seems to be correct but it is not creating users or databases in MySQL.

Update #3

Created the database "my_guitar_shop1" through PHPMyAdmin and now I get these errors with corresponding code just below each error message;

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: category_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\book_apps\ch05_guitar_shop\product_manager\index.php on line 16

```
if ($action == 'list_products') {
// Get the current category ID
$category_id = $_GET['category_id'];    <-----this is line #16
if (!isset($category_id)) {
    $category_id = 1;
}
```

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\book_apps\ch05_guitar_shop\model\category_db.php on line 15

```
function get_category_name($category_id) {
global $db;
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories
          WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
$category = $db->query($query);
$category = $category->fetch();                <-----this is line #15
$category_name = $category['categoryName'];
return $category_name;
}
```

Comment: You are using connecting as mgs_user. Maybe you should connect as root. Please show us the line where you connect to the db, and remove your password from it.

Comment: If I wanted to connect as "root" I would need to change the applications code in several different files. Shouldn't the PHP code be able to create new users that have access to the database?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that you didn't created the 'mgs_user' user, for this you can do something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'mgs_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then grant the appropriate permissions using:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseName.* To 'mgs_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: I posted the code that creates the user. Again this is taken from Murach's site. Does it look like it should work?

Comment: Well, the MySQL code is fine, if you're MySQL console savvy, then I recommend you to check that the user is really there, either by connecting as this user from MySQL console or by connecting as root and viewing the users and its permissions.

Comment: I checked through PHPMyAdmin and the user "mgs_user@localhost" was not there. I created the user and now I get an error that says "unknown database". I will post it above. What gives? I don't understand why the code is not working.

Comment: The code you posted is working, but most likely wasn't called before, as you already have the code to create the database, simply run a query on PHPMyAdmin to create it.

Comment: You mean create the database with PHPMyAdmin? I just did that and now I am getting another error which I have posted above. By the way thanks for the help so far Rafael.

Comment: This error (Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object) usually means that the query returned and empty set or failed, I recommend you to check the result of `query()`, in any case, most likely the tables that this example depends on, as the database and user, were not created either.

Comment: By the way, please post a question per problem you have, this help better both to you and the general site.

Comment: This is still part of the same problem. XAMPP does not work. Why does it not properly run the code?

Comment: XAMPP is working perfectly fine, the problem is that the database of your application wasn't created properly, if at all, you need to run all the database creation scripts yourself, either in MySQL's command prompt or in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when initially starting with the book, and the description the error message gives to "follow the instructions in chapter 1" isn't any help. If you go to the appendix at the back of the book, however, it gives a detailed explanation on how to run a script through phpMyAdmin that will create the appropriate databases needed for the exercises. If you're running Windows, the details are on page 818 and it cleared up the problem for me. Hope that helps.